# Calling an external function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, event-handling

I am setting up a function in a document ready function and that function needs to execute a function that is in an external javascript file.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/foo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     function newFunction(){
          nextFunction();
     }
     video.addListener('ended',function(){
          $("#div").hide();
          newFunction();
     });

});
```

external foo.js

```
function nextFunction(){
     alert("FOO!");
}
```

Now I have video playing, and a video.onended function that will execute newFunction() but newfunction will NOT execute nextFunction() even thought it WILL execute $("#div").hide();.  what am I doing wrong?

I realized that having the function inside a video.Event Listener MAY be a key to finding the answer, so I have added it to the original issue.

Comment: have you checked that newFunction() is getting called? Do you have any console errors?

Comment: I'm getting the error **Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function ** but it's not telling me whether my video.onended or my newFunction() is flagging the error

Comment: It should tell you a line number...

Comment: the thing that is confusing me the most, is that I have other commands in my newFunction() and they are executing properly, for example $("div").hide();

Comment: Your `$(document).ready(function () { ... })` isn't surrounded in a `<script></script>` tag. Typo, or possibly the issue?

If it is executing then `$('div').hide()` line, then it means that `nextFunction` is not defined. Check the console to verify that your script is loaded; could be getting a 404 because it is in a different location.

Comment: I had the same issue a couple of days ago. In my case i had a DOM element with a name the same as the function name. The error dissapeared after renaming one of them.

Comment: You are only calling `nextFunction` from inside `newFunction`, and the line before you try to call `nextFunction` works. Therefore the problem must be with the way you are defining `nextFunction`. The code you've shared with us, as Bic points out, won't even run the hide() function though. You need to produce a minimised test case that actually reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Bic an assumption that all javascript would be encapsulated in <script> tags. I assumes that was just a given.

Comment: @Murphy1976 — `<script src="external">script</script>` is a common cause of brokenness. Test cases that actually reproduce the problem are far easier to deal with then ones which vaguely indicate what the code is like.

Comment: ok... what I have done, is completely given up on the whole external to internal code communication.  I did realize that my external was ALSO running a document.ready function, so I put BOTH functions in the external javascript file and STILL, I am getting the **Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function (anonymous function)** it is detecting that nextFunction is flagging the error. I even swapped it from `function nextFunction()` to `nextFunction = function()` and I am still getting the error.

Comment: I dont think we have enough information to tell what your problem is. Just doing a simple plunker I am able to get it to work with the external file. http://plnkr.co/edit/bvtE2OBz2wsE3leglFdJ?p=preview